# How convert date time (char) columns to date time format in the same columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, date

In sample below the *new_date* column is in the expected format, the *date* column is in the chr format and the date is stored in it as a number.
Is there a way to convert date time (char) to date time format without creating a new column?

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2),
                 date = c("2013-09-15T00:00:00Z", "2014-09-13T00:00:00Z"), stringsAsFactors = F)

is.convertible.to.date <- function(x) !is.na(as.Date(as.character(x), tz = Sys.timezone(), format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))

str(df)
```

'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
id  : num  1 2
date: chr "2013-09-15T00:00:00Z" "2014-09-13T00:00:00Z"

```
DF_date <- sapply(df, is.convertible.to.date)
df$new_date <- as.Date(df[DF_date])
str(df)
```

'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
id      : num  1 2
date    : chr  "2013-09-15T00:00:00Z" "2014-09-13T00:00:00Z"
new_date: Date, format: "2013-09-15" "2014-09-13"

```
DF_date <- sapply(df, is.convertible.to.date)
df[DF_date] <- as.Date(df[DF_date])

str(df)
```

'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
id      : num  1 2
**date    : chr  "15963" "16326"**
new_date: Date, format: "2013-09-15" "2014-09-13"

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. You just want to overwrite an existing column? Easy: `df$date <- as.Date(df$date, tz = Sys.timezone(), format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2),
                 date = c("2013-09-15T01:00:00Z", "2014-09-13T00:00:00Z"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$date <- ymd_hms(df$date)
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ id  : num  1 2
# $ date: POSIXct, format: "2013-09-15 01:00:00" "2014-09-13 00:00:00"
```

I made a small change from `2013-09-15T00:00:00Z` to `2013-09-15T01:00:00Z`, so you see it easily.